# the view contains nested formatting which is not supported infopath 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-rules

we are getting below error while publishing the form.

> the view contains nested formatting which is not supported infopath 2013

Answer (score 0):

When the form nested formatting include heavily nested tables and heavily formatted text, it will get the error you mentioned.

Please check if the depth at which XML elements are nested in the file or the complexity of processing the file exceeds what the server supports, and simplify the nested formatting.